# Is there an epub reader for a PC which lets the user take notes?

Tags: epub, annotations, windows

I was asked if there is some software for a PC for reading ebooks (in epub format) and take notes in them. If I have ever to browse an ebook on a PC I use the reader in Calibre which does not offer this functionality, so I am at a loss. Which readers do exist which save notes? Being able to use them elsewhere is a plus, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the EPUB is DRM free, you can upload it to your Google Play Books account. Then if you enable note syncing from the mobile app, it'll save the notes in a doc on your Google Drive and use that to sync them across devices. The notes will show up in the web reader too, and changes you make on the web will show up on your other devices. Google has instructions for syncing notes here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6209737?hl=en

Answer (score 5):

You can read books and [add notes with Microsoft Edge](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-annotate-epub-files-microsoft-edge). However, you can't export them.

Answer (score 2):

freda lets you highlight and add notes, but you cannot underline text.

Also epub files doesn't save the notes in itself like pdf does. epub readers that support adding notes, including freda, save them externally. So if you open the epub file in another computer, the notes are lost.

Comment: is the external epub note a distinct file, so that if I copy it to the same epub reader software in my new device, then the notes can be shown in new device?